# Acessing data from a http request

Tags: html, http, server

I am writing a http handler for a server and I am looking directly at the http requests when they come in from different clients. I can easily deal with normal http requests. The problem occurs when I get a GET or POST request. I do not know how to access the data from the GET or the POST therefore I cannot continue. Could someone please point me in the direction of some where which deals with the issue on how to access the data. Thanks in advance.

Answer:

to do this:

In a GET request the data comes in the URL itself therefore just parse the URL from the HTTP request and look for the question mark and the arguments.

For a POST request there are 2 different ways however the main one means that the arguments are put in the body of the request like this:
q=hello&v=world
The length is specified in the request as well so if you need it is under Content-Length:

Comment: GET and POST are by far the two most common request methods. What do you mean by "normal" requests then? Maybe [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) would help?

Comment: Requests which only deal with sending back documents and not processing data

Comment: [RFC 2616 section 4.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.3) clearly and authoritatively defines the format of HTTP request bodies (and response bodies).

Comment: The way of reading parameters from an HTTP request depends on the languaje you are working on. Is it ASP? Java? PHP?